# Remoting JBoss AS 7 to AS 4 and vice versa

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, jboss-4.2.x

Is it possible to remotely access an EJB on a JBoss AS 4 from a JBoss AS 7 and vice versa (using EJB3)?

If so, how can I do it?

I am looking for any information about remoting between different JBoss Versions. There must be something on the web, but I'm struggling on finding the right search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

You have to create the remote interface and the bean on JBoss A4.

```
@javax.ejb.Remote
public interface JBossFourRemote{
    int doSomething();
}

@javax.ejb.Stateless
public JBossFourBean implements JBossFourRemote{
    public int doSomething(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Deploy that, and then call the bean from the JBoss AS 7 client as follows.

```
public void someJBossSevenMethod(String args[]){
    JBossFourRemote bean = (JBossFourRemote)new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/app/module/JBossFourBean!JBossFourRemote");
    bean.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: How does `lookup("java:global/app/module/JBossFourBean!JBossFourRemote")` manage to return a reference to an EJB hosted in a JBoss AS 4.x instance (possibly on another host)?